# Can I run gremlin queries on cosmos-db (graph) from azure databricks notebook?

Tags: apache-spark, graph, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-databricks

Is there a direct integration of Gremlin into azure databricks notebook ?

I have a graph into cosmosDb and I want to run some gremlin queries. For e.g

`g.V().hasLabel('x').out('y').out('z')`

I run the queries from azure portal but for a large set of data it will throw

> ["Request rate is large"]

Switching to Azure databricks, I've created a cluster, add "azure-cosmosdb-spark" library and from a python notebook a was able to run only sql queries like "SELECT * FROM c"

I've tried using spark-gremlin and hadoop-gremlin libraries, but the only way I can see is right now is to load all my nodes and edges into a dataFrame (label by label) and then change it into graphFrame and only then, after I rebuild the graph here I can make some traversal queries, but not Gremlin (yet). (and having millions of nodes and edges I don't know how much this can help me).

I will like to know if a direct gremlin query from notebook on cosmosDb is supported, or at least a direct migration of the graph into dataFrame ?

Answer (score -1):

This looks like what you need: https://link.medium.com/zkaW4VIVQT

Whilst the article is about writing to CosmosDB I think the methods could be applied to reading.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but unfortunately I know the article and the main problem is that I need to run Gremlin (search) queries. For the writing step I am using bulk operations.